# ClearScript + Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, node-modules, clearscript

So straight to the point:
I've been wondering ever since I found this awesome project if there could be a way to integrate basic node.js modules in it, like 'fs'/'path'/'sys'/...
I'm even keen to start a project on it, maybe even implementing node's import system.
I'd like to know if there's some limitation clearscript imposes that could prevent this kind of things.

Thanks for your patience! :D

Comment: Why not ask on the ClearScript discussion site? https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript/discussions

Comment: Didn’t even know it existed, thanks!

Comment: Hey there @NicolaLeoneCiardi, please be aware of the community guidelines and the tips&tricks that you should apply to the question you are asking, then you won't get any downvotes ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.